# ¿Cómo condicionar un componente mat datepicker para que solo se muestre cuando haya datos?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde el campo **FECHA REGISTRO** es de tipo Date, y quiero que muestre un datepicker, el cual ya lo hace, pero quiero que se muestre solo cuando tenga datos, si no hay datos en    **[value]="element.fechaRegistro"** que no se pinte el datepicker o que aparezca como deshabilitado

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-select
          [(value)]="element.cveEstado"
          (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
        >
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel"
            [value]="estatus.cveEstado"
            [ngClass]="{
              'text-red': estatus.cveEstado == 'ERR',
              'text-blue': estatus.cveEstado == 'INP'
            }"
          >
            {{ estatus.descripcion }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          [value]="element.comentario"
          (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.horaInicio }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="picker"
          [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
          (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)"
        />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
          matIconSuffix
          [for]="picker"
        ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

actualmente se pinta en todos los registros , y quiero que solo salga el datepicker donde si hay datos, como en los dos últimos registros por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un `*ngIf`

Comment: Acá ejemplos oficiales de *ngIf  https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: lo estoy tratando de agregar en la propiedad disable,  de esta forma   [disabled]="*ngIf control.fechaProceso == '' vacio "

Comment: pero esa condicion tiene que ir dentro del input? o en la eetiqueta del mat -datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con agregar un `*ngIf` que verifique si existe el valor.

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
```

Agrego un ejemplo:

**HTML**

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Fecha">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Fecha</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="row.fecha">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="row.fecha" />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]